# Windows 10, Microsoft VLC image downloads - any way to use a download manager?

Tags: windows-10

Trying to download the Server 2016 images for quite some time now, and all I get are corrupt images.

Prior to windows 10 I could use the Microsoft download manager - which had nice features like checksums. Edge does not seem to integrate at all.

I am now past my 10th attempt to get that ISO image down without corruption.

What is the new way to reliably download those 5+ GB ISO images when using Windows 10 as a client?

Comment: Try with IE, not edge. The download manager was offered only in IE

Comment: But it also relied on Java, IIRC, and some ActiveX. I tried IE and nothing sensibly came up.

Comment: Not sure if this is more reliable, but you could try with PowerShell: `$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient; $client.DownloadFile("http://...","C:\...")`. And for the Checksum use `Get-FileHash ... -Algorithm MD5`.

Comment: Well, for the checksum - I first need to get one. I am unable to find a reference for the VLC download of Server 2016. I am right now copying Windows ( to a remote data center in the USA and will isntall it on a VM there just to get the download manager.

Comment: Just FYI, I successfully downloaded 2016 Server via the Volume Licensing Service Center using Chrome and IE on Windows 10 with the latest patches.

Comment: That is all nice. I did not. I actually did not even with a WIn 8.1 image using the download manager. THere is either a bad image somewhere on my akamai server, or a transparent proxy of a provider interferes. I finally moved my 8.1 image over to a data center and got it from there. Still I would like to know how to use the download manager in Win 10.